# Continuous function on the unit sphere

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Let S$^2$ := $\lbrace$ x $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$$^3$ : $\Vert x\Vert$$_2$ $\rbrace$ $\subset$ ($\mathbb{R}$$^3$, $\Vert .\Vert$$_2$) and T: S$^2$ $\to$ ($\mathbb{R}$, $\vert x\vert$ ) a continuous function.

a) Is there a point x$_0$ $\in$ S$^2$ such that T(x$_0$) = T(-x$_0$) ?

b) Is there a value T $\in$ (Tmax,Tmin), which exactly one x $\in$ S$^2$ takes, with Tmax = sup $\lbrace$ T(x) : x $\in$ S$^2$ $\rbrace$ and Tmin = inf $\lbrace$ T(x) : x $\in$ S$^2$ $\rbrace$ ?

I think I have a example of a function in a) : Let T(x) = cos (x$_1$) with x = (x$_1$, x$_2$, x$_3$)$^T$, so take for example x$_0$=(1,0,0)$^T$, so is T(x$_0$)=T(-x$_0$), however I don't know how to start b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, you have to assert an answer that holds generally, not just for one function. Let $f(x)=T(x)-T(-x)$ and apply the Intermediate Value Theorem.

For the second, if possible let $y_0$ be such a value. Restrict $T$ to $\mathbb{S}^2\setminus{x_0}$ and use the fact that a continuous image of a connected set is connected.

Comment: Thank for the well explained part a) ! However I am not sure I understand your idea for part b) : Do I assume that such an y exist ? And I don't really see the consequence of the image of T being connected....

Comment: $T$ maps $\mathbb{S^2}\setminus \{x_0\}$ to a disconnected interval. That is impossible since $\mathbb{S^2}\setminus \{x_0\}$ is connected and $T$ is continuous.

Comment: Ok it is clearer but what I don't understand is why does T map S^2 \{xo} to a disconnected interval ?

Comment: What is the image of $T$?

Comment: We know the image of x by T is a real number, so I claim that the image of T is a subset of the real numbers. I know that S$\^2$ is connected and that the image of a continuous function from a connected set is again connected but I don't see why  T maps S$\^2$ \ {x$\_0$} to a disconnected interval

Comment: Since $\mathbb{S}^2$ is compact and connected, image of $T$ must be compact and connected as well, which means it is going to be a closed interval, with $y_0$ in the interior. Now since the only pre-image of $y_0$ is $x_0$, image of $\mathbb{S^2}\setminus x_0$ is going to be the whole interval minus the point $y_0$, which is disconnected.

Comment: Oh I understand now !! Thank you for your good explanations !